# Array won't replace multiples of 2

Tags: java, arrays

I want to replace all multiples of 2 in my array with the value 0 and I felt as though this code did this but 4,6 and 8 stay the same in the output.
Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

```
public static void markOfMultiples(int[]listOfNumbers, int number)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<listOfNumbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (listOfNumbers[i]%number == 0)
        {
            listOfNumbers[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the input and output? and confirm that the parameter you supplied for the argument 'number' is 2

Comment: How do you invoke this method?

Comment: The method looks OK. Show how you're using it.

Comment: Does the call of `markOfMultiples` actually use `2` as a value for the argument `number`?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I'm stupid.
Thanks for the help anyways guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mycase your method was working fine,It solely depends how you are invoking your method

You should invoke your method like

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        int num[]={2,4,6,11,13,8};
        markOfMultiples(num,2);


}
```

Your method remains the same

```
public static void markOfMultiples(int[]listOfNumbers, int number)
    {
          for(int i = 0; i<listOfNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfNumbers[i]%number == 0)
                {
                      listOfNumbers[i] = 0;
                }
            System.out.println(listOfNumbers[i]);//added by me to track what's going on
        }
```

and its working fine!